# SQL PRINT with InfoMessage

Tags: c#, stored-procedures

How do you go about distinguishing between and error message and a PRINT in a SQL Query?

```
void myConnection_InfoMessage(object sender, SqlInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Errors.Count > 0)
     {
     }
}
```

It sees PRINT statements as an error.

How can I distinguish between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each error, which is an `SqlError` object, you can examine the [`Class`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.class%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

> Messages with a severity level of 10 or less are informational and indicate problems caused by mistakes in information that a user has entered. Severity levels from 11 through 16 are generated by the user, and can be corrected by the user. Severity levels from 17 through 25 indicate software or hardware errors. When a level 17, 18, or 19 error occurs, you can continue working, although you might not be able to execute a particular statement.

`PRINT`s come through with a `Class` of 0, but generally you should (as it says) treat 10 or lower as "informational" rather than a real error.

Comment: They are all coming back as a class of 0

Comment: Sorry, I think it was due to the fact that it was printing :P